# Login to a website using requests post method

Tags: python, perl, post, authentication, request

I am trying to login to this website : https://www.blackrock.com/userplatform/signOn

And I am using the following script to do so :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0'
}
resp = requests.get('https://www.ishares.com/us/sign-on.saml', headers=headers)

soup_object =  BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

csrf = soup_object.select_one('meta[name="_csrf"]').get('content')

login_data = dict(userName='USERNAME', password='PASSWORD', csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrf)

r = requests.post('https://www.blackrock.com/userplatform/signOn', data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "https://www.blackrock.com"})
```

However, when I run the script in postman it gives me forbidden 403 error message. Can somebody please suggest what am I doing wrong?

The site has even shared a script for login into their portal and downloading some files. But it is written in perl. Sharing that script for reference.  But I want to do it using python.

```
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use URI qw( );

my $thisScript = basename($0);
print "==START $thisScript==\n";
my ($help, $proxy, $username, $password);
my $urlsToBeDownloaded = "file-url-list.txt";
my $url = "https://www.ishares.com/us/sign-on.saml";
usage() if (@ARGV < 2 or ! GetOptions('proxy:s' => \$proxy, 
                                      'username=s' => \$username, 
                                      'password=s' => \$password) 
                        or defined $help);

if ($username eq "" || $password eq "") {
        usage();
}

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
if($proxy ne ""){
    $mech->proxy(['http', 'https'], $proxy);    
}
$mech->get($url);
$mech->submit();
my $ctoken = $mech->field('ctoken');

$mech->get($mech->uri());
$mech->submit_form(
        form_number => 1,
        fields    => {
                        userName => $username,
                        password  => $password,
                        ctoken  => $ctoken
                     }
);
$mech->submit();
if($mech->content() =~ "sign-out.saml" ){
    open (FILE, $urlsToBeDownloaded)or die "Can't open $urlsToBeDownloaded for read: $!";
    while (<FILE>) {
        chomp;
        print "Downloading==>$_ \n";
        eval {
            $mech->get($_);
            $mech->save_content(getFileNameFromUrl($_));    
        };
        if($@){
            print "ERROR: Downloading $_. $@\n";
        }
    }
    close (FILE);
} else {
    print "ERROR: Invalid email or password. Please try again.\n";  
}
print "==END $thisScript==\n";

sub getFileNameFromUrl{
    my $uri = URI->new($_[0]);
    return ( $uri->path_segments )[-1];
}

sub usage {
        print "\nUsage: perl $thisScript --proxy <Set the proxy (OPTIONAL)> --username <User Name> --password <Password> \n\n";
        print("Ex: perl $thisScript --proxy \"http://proxyurl\" --username \"testuser\@test.com\" --password \"password\" \n\n");
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 3rd key is **_csrf** and not **csrfmiddlewaretoken** in login_data variable:

= >

```
login_data = dict(userName='USERNAME', password='PASSWORD', _csrf=csrf)
```

Comment: Nice catch. But still not able to login.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use requests.session it will store and update all cookies and headers automatically, so you dont have to add them each request.

Second in the perl script I can see they srt ctoken, i guess this is csrf token. So your post data should look like this:

```
{
“userName”: “your username”,
“password”: “your password”,
“ctoken”: “the csrf token”
}
```

Also dont forget to update the csrf token after each request.

Comment: Even for 'ctoken' it gives forbidden message. However, for '_csrf' it gives html response stating 'Not able to access your account'